# Not case sensitive comparison of strings

Tags: java, string, comparison, case-insensitive

I have this currently (and much more) and want to make it so that if someone types something in from the array that isn't uppercase(it is currently all uppercase), then they can still order it.

```
if(food.equals(array[0])) {
    System.out.println("Here is your " + food + ".");
}
```

Comment: food.equalsIgnoreCase(array[0]) ??

Comment: I have the code for it in other places, this is a small portion of code.

Comment: I knew, a question like this must have been already answered in StackOverflow, IMO

Answer (score 5):

Use [equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `equals`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, wish I could accept earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
food.equalsIgnoreCase(array[0])
```

It's documented, in the [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `equals()`

Answer (score 0):

The other way to go about this is to ensure that everything stored in your array is lowercase, then do `food = food.toLowerCase();` before testing whether `food.equals()` something in your array.

If you had a very tight performance requirement for this part of your application, you might choose to run the comparison this way.

Comment: Another possibility is to create a Food class that knows how to compare itself case insensitively (overriding equals and hashCode), and use that instead of strings.